# Force close when starting new activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to launch a new activity from my main activity, but I just get error codes all the time.

Heres my main activity;

```
   package com.gunstats;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class gunstats extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 


        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deagle);

        Button button3 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();


            }

        });

        final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ak47);

        Button button2 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp2.start();

            }

        });


        final MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.m40a3);

        Button button1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp3.start();

            }
        });



        Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
                button4.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(gunstats.this,
                                more.class);
                                                 startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                        });

    }

}
```

and the activity that is being called from my main class;

```
package com.gunstats;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class more extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 


        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deagle);

        Button buttonm1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonm1);
        buttonm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();


            }

        });


    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.gunstats"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".gunstats"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


            </intent-filter>


         </activity>

                                  <activity android:name=".more"/>

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
01-08 17:37:47.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gunstats/com.gunstats.more}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.gunstats.more.onCreate(more.java:23)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
01-08 17:37:47.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     ... 11 more
```

The error is pointing to my 23 line in the 'more' class.

my 23 line is;
buttonm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> And there's nothing wrong in the manifest

I think there probably is.  This error line:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.gunstats/com.gunstats.more}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 01-08
```

Suggests you haven't defined the `Activity` "more" in the manifest.  Check that it is defined.

Also, Java convention is that class names have the first letter capitalised.  So the class should be called `More`.

Comment: Alex, sounds like `findViewById(R.id.buttonm1)` is returning `null`. Make sure you definitely have a button with the id `@+id/buttonm1` in `res/layout/main.xml`.

Comment: @Alex: you're trying to use a null object, try to figure out which object is null. It's probably `buttonm1`.

Comment: Wops, wrong line, my 23 line (where the error is);
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

All the buttons are in the right xml file.

Comment: That line doesn't appear in the code you posted.  Since your original problem is now fixed, perhaps you would be better off starting a new question for the new issue?

Comment: You haven't actually said what the error on that line is.  If it's a `NullPointer` then you should follow the suggestion that Dave made in the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

You should add "more" Activity to the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Hi.
 <activity android:name=".more" />

Is in my manifest, but it still aint workin :/

Comment: Hi Alex, is your 'more' Activity refer to right package where 'more' Activity exist ? please check your manifest package also !

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry, but I really dont know how you mean.
Once I've created a new activity I just put "<activity android:name=".more" />"
in the manifest.
Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: @Alex: edit your question and post your manifest xml contents. This will remove all confusions. also, check the "package xyz" (should be the very first line of each activity class file) and post them too.

Comment: I mean is your manifest package should be the same with your 'more' Activity. ex : package="com.bsoft.activity" and activity is <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">. so the dot(.) in android:name ".SplashActivity" refer to package "com.bsoft.activity"

Comment: "more" and "gunstats" is in the same package.